# Coredata and UITableViewController row re-order

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a UITableViewController that is displaying rows from my NSFetchedResultsController. My has several sections, with the rows being ordered within each section, using an 'order' field.

I'm using fairly bog-standard code to handle the moving of rows. The rows moves are restricted to the section they are contained within.   When a row rearrange takes place, I use the following code..

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)destinationIndexPath
{
    self.fetchedResultsController.delegate = nil;

    NSMutableArray *myImages = [[self.fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects] mutableCopy];

    // Grab the item we're moving.
    NSManagedObject *myImage = [[self fetchedResultsController] objectAtIndexPath:sourceIndexPath];

    // Remove the object we're moving from the array.
    [myImages removeObject:myImage];

    // Now re-insert it at the destination.....here lies the problem???
    [myImages insertObject:myImage atIndex [destinationIndexPath row]];

    // All of the objects are now in their correct order. Update each
    // object's displayOrder field by iterating through the array.
    int i = 0;
    for (MyImage *myImage in myImages)
    {
        myImage.order = [NSNumber numberWithInt:i];
        i++;
    }

    // Save the data here!

    self.fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
}
```

(Some variable names have been changed to protect the innocent!!!)

This works quite well but doesn't always perform as expected. The reason being (I think) is I'm removing the object from the array successfully, but insertion again is wrong because it uses the absolute row index of the whole array, without allowing for the fact that this may be in (say) the second or third section of the UITableView/NSFetchedResultsController.

So, how can I put an object back into my mutable array (which is linear) into my the correct index, given the destination indexPath is two-dimensional?  (I could probably count previous rows/section) but wonder if there's a prettier way.)

Thanks

Comment: I think you need is something to act as a holding container for the sections of the table and within those sections, an array of the objects, which is what you have already. To extend what you have already I'd suggest using a NSMutableDictionary as the holding object and for each section of the table you have a dictionary object with key representing the value being an array of you table cell objects (images??). By adding an 'outer control' you can reference each section's array of images by key and array index and add and delete with safety. Let me know if this approach helps?

Comment: Thanks...your comments 'nudged' me and I have got working.  I got the NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo for the sourceIndexPath and the got a mutable copy of the images within that section only. Then I can safely rearrange.  I was stumped initially because the FRC still wasn't 'responding' by re-ordering until I set it to nil, which caused it to re-query. Whether this last stage is right or not is questionable, but it seems to work in my case.

Comment: Glad I could help a bit, I find a lot of 'problems' are usually more of an approach issue, and sometimes a second pair of eyes can help, even if not supplying a solution, can open the thought process. I'd appreciate a vote up on my first comment if you think I deserve one.

Comment: My pleasure. It's working well.